# Custom Actionbar error NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, action

i have created example for Customise Actionbar with use of SetCustomview()

now i am getting an error **NullPointerException** at **Actionbar.setCustomView();**

im my class i am extending with Collection can anyone help me ?

Comment: Yes,there is something `null`.Please post code and full stacktrace.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ[use this link for code](https://github.com/Gupta126/code/blob/master/mainfile) in that line number 96 where i am geting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `getActionBar()` returns null.

Replace line 60 by these two:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i detect a issue as you provided Thanks again but thing is that it cans show title of app and logo can you tell me why this happens ?

Comment: When I first came across this problem, I found [this.](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html) May be help.

Comment: thanks man can you check my this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654076/customise-actionbar-dont-show-title-of-app)